# Cant add reference to a worker service in C#

Tags: windows-services, visual-studio-2022

I am trying and following a tutorial to add a Windows Service into mi WebApp to send emails periodically...

The main thing I can not do is add the ServiceProcess reference to use the ServiceBase.

I tried it almost all in Visual Studio 2022, but I can not add the reference.. Either I can not find it in the Reference Library and if I look for the System.ServiceProcess.dll and try adding it manually, but I get the **"The reference is invalid or unsupported"**. I do not know how to extend or apply it in a Worker Service (I was not able to create the project in Windows Service in Visual Studio 2022, I was not able to find any option, I just got the Worker Service).

I am losing it with this...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.. Apparently, I needed the .NET desktop development workload in my Visual Studio 2022.

Documentation should be really clearer in the 2022 installer. So many things changed so much...